# Using event in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, validation, events

I have two textboxes in WPF. named txt1 and txt2.

In the lostFocus of txt1 I write

```
If txt1.Text is nothing then 
    txt1.Focus
End If
```

In the lostFocus event of txt2 I write

```
If txt2.Text is nothing then
    txt2.Focus
End If
```

Now, If txt1 and txt2 are both empty and user presses TAB key in txt1 the problem occurs. Program goes in infinite loop. I mean cursor comes to txt1 and goes to txt2 infinite times.I know This is normal behavior according to my code.

So I want to have validating event to avoid the problems like above. But I cannot find one in WPF.
So which event should I use?

Comment: Instead of setting the focus back to the TextBox that lose focus why not outline the TextBox in red showing that the field needs data or display a MessageBox? Or why not hold validation until the end of the form is reached and a user presses a submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a VB coder so can't write exact code for you but here is what you should do. Add event handler for event PreviewLostKeyboardFocus. inside the event handler set e.Handled to true if the text is empty.
Sample C# code. I have writter a generic handler.

```
private void TextBox_PreviewLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((sender as TextBox).Text))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what about loosing focus due to mouse?

Comment: @Vishal this is not what you had asked earlier. Did you even try the code I suggested? This code would put the focus back on textbox even when you use the mouse.

Comment: I am sorry from the bottom of my heart for ignoring your answer. This is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to allow the user to navigate away from the empty/null text box but either revert the text to the initial value (if there was one) or provide a validation error.  Providing validation errors is relatively easy with IDataErrorInfo.

As a software user myself I get annoyed when an application prevents me from navigating away from a field.

**Reset Value Approach**

See this stackoverflow appraoch for how to maintain and get the previous value.  In the LostFocus event you can set your member variable back to _oldValue if the current value is invalid.
[determine a textbox's previous value in its lost focused event? WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299784/determine-a-textboxs-previous-value-in-its-lost-focused-event-wpf)

**Validation Approach**

Those two dates are stored in a model or a view model class.  In that class implement IDataErrorInfo (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx).  Then in your xaml you can show the validation errors.

```
//This is your model/viewmodel validation logic
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        string result = null;
        if (columnName == "FirstName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                result = "Please enter a First Name";
        }
        if (columnName == "LastName")
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                result = "Please enter a Last Name";
        }
       if (columnName == "Age")
        {
            if (Age < = 0 || Age >= 99)
                result = "Please enter a valid age";
        }
        return result;
    }
}

//Here is a sample of a xaml text block
<textbox x:Name="tbFirstName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Validation.Error="Validation_Error" Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Path=FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true}" />
```

You can also look at these other StackOverflow posts-
[What is IDataErrorInfo and how does it work with WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883803/what-is-idataerrorinfo-and-how-does-it-work-with-wpf)
[IDataErrorInfo notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399915/idataerrorinfo-notification)

Comment: I am on the starting part of my accounting project. There I need twoo dates from the user. Financial Year Starting Date and Financial Year Ending Date and both are required. So, what do you suggest in this case?

Comment: Don't enable the next actions until these two fields pass validation (are not null).

Comment: thanks for the suggetion. But the problem has been solved by Nishant.